# Neither FileOutputCommitter.commitTask nor abortTask are invoked

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a custom `OutputFileFormat` with a custom `FileOutputCommitter`.  I've noticed that although my `FileOutputCommitter.commitJob` & `abortJob` are invoked the `commitTask & abortTask` are not being invoked.

I've also overridden the two `needTaskCommit` methods to return true.

Comment: So, how did you use or set your custom output committer?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker, i'm not setting my output committer.  I'm making it available through a getter in my custom outputFileFormat.  I think the output committer is being accessed since the commit or abort job methods are invoked.

Comment: I am having the same issue. You are using MultipleOutputs I'm guessing?